# set the animation to the activity without xml file

Tags: android

Hi I want  to set the animation to an activity without xml file.Please give me some suggestions on this topic.Thanks in advance

Comment: create a separate thread and update gui in that thread using handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AnimationSet myAnimation = new AnimationSet(true);
// Create a translate animation
/* TranslateAnimation animation=new TranslateAnimation(0,0,237,0);
animation.setDuration(250);
// Add each animation to the set
myAnimation.addAnimation(animation);*/
ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation((float)0.5, (float)1, (float)0.5, (float)1);
scale.setFillAfter(true);
scale.setDuration(500);
<activity name>.startAnimation(scale);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Animation createAnimation() {
    final Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    return animation;
}
```

Simple alpha animation, the way to create others is pretty much the same.

Use view.startAnimation(yourAnimation) to start animation, and yourAnimation.reset() before reusing the same animation again.

P.S. Maybe I misunderstood you, and you want an animation between activity changes?